# How I can change the name of multiple files at once in R or terminal?

Tags: r, perl, linux, shell, awk

I have 200 .vcf files in a folder with long names like

```
LP6005409-DNA_E03_vs_LP6005408-DNA_E03.snp.pass.vcf
```

How can I change the name of each file to, for example `A1.vcf ....A200.vcf`?

Renaming these files manually takes ages, help please.

```
> file.rename(list.files(pattern = "vcf"), paste0("A",1:length(list.files(pattern = ".vcf")),".vcf"))
Error in file.rename(list.files(pattern = "vcf"), paste0("A", 1:length(list.files(pattern = ".vcf")),  : 
  'from' and 'to' are of different lengths


[fi1d18@cyan01 new]$ for i in *.vcf; do echo mv $i A${k}.vcf ; k=`echo "1+${k}" | bc`; done
mv LP2000325-DNA_A01_vs_LP2000317-DNA_A01.snp.pass.vcf A.vcf
(standard_in) 2: syntax error
mv LP6008031-DNA_A04_vs_LP6008032-DNA_D03.snp.pass.vcf A.vcf
(standard_in) 2: syntax error
[fi1d18@cyan01 new]$ for i in *.vcf; do mv $i A${k}.vcf ; k=`echo "1+${k}" | bc`; done
(standard_in) 2: syntax error
mv: try to overwrite `A.vcf', overriding mode 0500 (r-x------)?
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

just to complete your question, you can do it in R in one line.

After setting the directory as your working directory, just type the following:

```r
file.rename(list.files(pattern = "vcf"), paste0("A",1:length(list.files(pattern = ".vcf")),".vcf"))
```

Maybe you can try `file.rename(list.files(pattern = ".vcf"), paste0("A",1:length(list.files(pattern = ".vcf")),".vcf"))`. Also, if there is still an error, can you post the output of `list.files(pattern = ".vcf")` just to see the structure of your files in folder (maybe one file has a weird name not detected by the pattern).

Answer (score 9):

Use `perl-rename`. This is usually called `rename` on Debian-based systems like Ubuntu or Mint, and `perl-rename` or `prename` on others. Assuming you have it as `rename`, you can simply do:

```
rename -n 's/.*\.vcf/"A" . ++$c . ".vcf"/e' *snp.pass.vcf
```

The `-n` causes `rename` to only print what it would do, without doing anything. So once you make sure it does what you want, run the command again without the `-n`.

Comment: On a Mac, you may need to install it first. Use `brew install rename` or use `zmv` in zsh (not bash) shell: https://superuser.com/q/152627/

Comment: @TimurShtatland note that there are [many renames](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/229230/22222) in the Linux world, just to keep things interesting ;)

Answer (score 3):

If your filenames do not contain blank spaces, you can do it with a for-loop in `bash`:

Make a test run with `echo` so that the command is only printed but not yet executed:

```
for i in *.vcf; do echo mv $i A${k}.vcf ; let k++ ; done
```

And if the result looks good remove the `echo` statement to execute the `mv` commands:

```
for i in *.vcf; do mv $i A${k}.vcf ; let k++ ; done
```

Comment: Sorry I tried your code and I got error mentioned in the main post

Comment: @Angel note that there is no reason to use `bc` even if you do choose to do it this way. `((k++))` or `k=$((k+1))` or `let k++` all work to increment the value of a shell variable: `k=0; while [[ $k -lt 10 ]]; do echo $k; ((k++)); done`. Alternatively: `for((k=0; k<=10;k++)); do echo $k; done`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment!

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT:**

*(Based on the comments by @terdon, with minor changes)*

Try this Perl one-liner. It is recommended for general use, even if your file names contain "unexpected" characters such as newlines.

```
perl -e 'for ( 0..$#ARGV ) { rename $ARGV[$_] => "A@{[ $_ + 1 ]}.vcf"; } ' *pass.vcf
```

Here, `-e` tells `perl` to look for code on the command line instead of a file with the script. `@ARGV` is the array of the command line arguments, here, files with old names.

`for ( 0..$#ARGV ) { ... }` loop goes through the indexes of elements of this array, assigning each implicitly to `$_`. The first argument to `rename` is the old file name: `$ARGV[$_]`. Instead of the comma separator of the method arguments I use `=>` synonym for clarity in this method call.

The new file name is the second argument. `@{[ ... ]}` inside the double quotes is the Perl idiom to evaluate the expression inside, which is `$_ + 1`, to make the file numbering start with 1. If you don't care about this, it is easier to make it start with 0: just use `"A$_.vcf"`, or, better, `"A${_}.vcf"`. The last form needs to be used for cases like this: `"A${_}pass.vcf"` to prevent Perl from treating `$_pass` as a variable, where `$_` is intended.

**DEPRECATED:**

Use the one-liner below when you are sure that the old file names do not have "unexpected" characters such as newlines. It is not for general use, see: [Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

It will work with the example shown by the OP. It also works with blanks and tabs in the file names, but it **breaks when file names have newlines**.

The (deprecated) Perl one-liner:

```
ls *.pass.vcf | perl -lne 'rename $_, "A$..vcf";'
```

Here, `ls |` lists all files with old names, one per line and passes the stdout into stdin of the next command, which is the Perl one line script. `-l` removes the new lines from the input. `-n` reads the input one line at a time. These are all commonly used command line Perl options.

In the one liner script, `$_` is the line read from stdin, and `$.` is the line number.

Comment: That is a slick perl one liner